# I am not able to use enumerate function properly

Tags: python, svm, enumerate

I have write down a code to enumerate char "a" from a text file (simple text document copied from pdf):

```
input_f = open('/home/zebrafish/Desktop/stackq/doc.txt','r')

#text i used in "doc.txt file"
#
#unctional similarities between the ATP binding pockets of
#kinases or between chemotypes of inhibitors that cannot
#be predicted from the sequence of the kinase or the
#chemical structure of the inhibitor.
#We first compared PI3-K family members according to

output_f = open('/home/zebrafish/Desktop/stackq/svm_in.txt','w')


for line in input_f :
    a = line
    print "\n",
    for y in enumerate([x[0] for x in enumerate(line) if x[1]=='a']): 
        a = ("%d:%d" % (y[0]+1,y[1]+1))
        #print a,
        output_f.write(a+" ")        

input_f.close()
output_f.close()
```

output of this code look like this if i run this script without generating the output file as per my requirement, for each line it calculate the position of "a" with frequency, as in first line "a" appeared in two times first at 8th position and second at 16th position and hence enumerated as "1:8 2:16" and so one for each and every line:

```
1:8 2:16 
1:4 2:47 3:51 
1:42 
1:7 
1:14 2:26 3:40
```

but when i write down output in a text file "svm_in.txt" with "output_f.write()" output is very wired .
some thing like this:

```
1:8 2:16 1:4 2:47 3:51 1:42 1:7 1:14 2:26 3:40
```

how can i get result in a output file for each line with "+" sine at the beginning of line like this:

```
+ 1:8 2:16 
+ 1:4 2:47 3:51 
+ 1:42 
+ 1:7 
+ 1:14 2:26 3:40
```

Comment: You need to write `'\n'` newline characters to the file, not `print` them.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but I have a suggestion to make your code more idiomatic. When using `enumerate`, give two variables in the target list of the expression: `([index for index, char in enumerate(line) if char=='a'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
for line in input_f:

    # find the positions of As in the line
    positions = [n for n, letter in enumerate(line, 1) if letter == 'a']

    # Create list of strings of the form "x:y"
    pairs = [("%d:%d" % (i, n)) for i, n in enumerate(positions, 1)]

    # Join all those strings into a single space-separated string
    all_pairs = ' '.join(pairs)

    # Write the string to the file, with a + sign at the beginning
    # and a newline at the end
    output_f.write("+ %s\n" % all_pairs)
```

You can modify the string in the last line to control how the line will be written in the output file.

Comment: thanks for explaining each line, can you please explain me this part of the code " "%d:%d" % " thanks :)

Comment: It creates a string of two integers separated by a colon (`:`). The tuple at the right-hand side of the `%` are the integers. As an example, type this into the python console: `'%d:%d' % (1, 2)`

Answer (score 3):

Don't print your newlines, write them to the file instead:

```
for line in input_f :
    output_f.write("\n+ ")
    for y in enumerate([x[0] for x in enumerate(line) if x[1]=='a']): 
        a = ("%d:%d" % (y[0]+1,y[1]+1))
        output_f.write(a + " ")
```

You could use some tuple unpacking to make it a little clearer what you are enumerating, and you can drop the `[..]` list comprehension and use a generator expression instead (saves some memory and processing):

```
for i, pos in enumerate((pos for pos, char in enumerate(line, 1) if char == 'a'), 1):
    output_f.write('%d:%d ' % (i, pos))
```

I also gave the `enumerate()` function a second argument, the start value, so you don't have to `+ 1` each number, and added the space in the file output in the string formatting.

You would normally write the newline *after* writing a line; and if you wanted a counter per line, add another enumerate::

```
for count, line in enumerate(input_f, 1):
    output_f.write("%d+ " % count)
    for i, pos in enumerate((pos for pos, char in enumerate(line, 1) if char == 'a'), 1):
        output_f.write('%d:%d ' % (i, pos))
    output_f.write('\n')
```

or, by using `str.join()` you can create a whole line in one go, using formatting to include the prefix and newline in one formatting operation:

```
for count, line in enumerate(input_f, 1):
    positions = (pos for pos, char in enumerate(line, 1) if char == 'a')
    line = ' '.join(['%d:%d' % (i, pos) for i, pos in enumerate(positions, 1)])
    output_f.write("%d+ %s\n" % (count, line))
```

which neatly avoids a trailing space as well.

Comment: @Martijn 100 likes and 100 votes thanks a lot i have been struggling for 3 hours, actually i am a beginner rather simply copy past i was trying to lean my self. : thaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks :)

Comment: @martijn hey two small Quarry came into my mind when i made corrections in my script as you have suggested. First,  statement "output_f.write("\n+ ")" adding unwanted new line character at the beginning and second, how can i add line numbers before "+" like this    1+ 1:8 2:16 
        2+ 1:4 2:47 3:51                                                      i have tried something but its not working   thanks

Comment: @user2935002: The join proposed by Roberto is actually going to avoid the newline at the start better. I'll update to add a counter for you.

Comment: @user2935002: counter and join added.

Comment: @Martijn Yes i was trying with Roberto's code and i also found the same, its avoiding new line and finally i  add the counter too, its generating the line number before plus sine thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2935002: my version is a *little* more efficient than his, but the difference is a lot smaller now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yehh i have just tried, now your code is perfectly fine for me thanks